# Do you use a pop-up dictionary/thesaurus on Windows? What are your criteria?

Tags: resources, tools, software

I used to use WordWeb as a pop-up dictionary/thesaurus while I wrote, but I found it lacking, particularly in its inability to let me define my own terms per context (for example, when writing about roller derby, I used particular words and synonyms that weren't generally known or suggested by the software).

What do you use, and what benefits did you get?

Comment: Do you have the "pro" of WordWeb? I have WordWeb Pro 6, and it allows one to not only add new words, but also add new meanings to existing words via the Edit menu.

Comment: I'll have to look into that. It was a pretty good program.

Comment: Please be aware that longer answers are more helpful than shorter ones.

Answer (score 3):

Being active in three language I use [Google's translate](http://translate.google.com) a lot. For a thesaurus I use [Interglot](http://www.interglot.com/). Just translate from english to english and you will get your synonyms. I don't know how it compares to WordWeb, but this is what I use.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I made [Scribodroid](http://www.igorsevo.com/Product.aspx?product=Scribodroid). It is a program for synonyms, collocations, rhymes and definitions. It searches online dictionaries and works as a pop-up tool in any word editing program. It can be very useful sometimes.